# как распарсить json массив

Tags: android, json

json такова вида 
http://namaz.muftyat.kz/api/times/2017/50.3/57.166667

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_detials, "GET", param);

Log.d("myLog", param.toString());
Log.d("myLog", json.toString());

// Успешно получинна детальная информация о продукте
JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);

Log.d("myLog", "objets ==="+ productObj.toString());

Log.d("myLog", "date ==="+ productObj.toString());
```

TAG_PRODUCT=result;
от первой скобки избавится получается как добраться до 
date
Fajr
Sunrise и.т.д. что бы потом использовать эти переменные 
заранее благодарен

в лог выводит

> objets
>   ===[[{"date":"01-01-2017","Fajr":"07:31","Sunrise":"09:06","Dhuhr":"13:20","Asr":"15:38","Maghrib":"17:24","Isha":"18:59"},{"date":"02-01-2017","Fajr":...............

Comment: судя по логу у вас дважды упакован один массив в другой `objets === [[ ... ]]`. измените логику сервера или вытаскивайте для парсинга первые элементы обоих массивов.

Comment: сервер не мой изменить не могу можно пример кода как вытащить первые элементы ?

Comment: повторяете это 2 раза: `JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);` (сначала вытаскиваете первый элемент внешнего массива, потом также вытаскиваете первый элемент внутреннего массива).

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. `JSONArray productObj` является массивом, каждый элемент которого, в свою очередь, так же является массивом, содержащим конечные объекты.

Чтобы получить доступ к конечным элементам - запускайте цикл.

```
JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);
for (int i = 0; i < productObj.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray innerArray = productObj.getJSONArray(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < innerArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject obj = innerArray.getJSONObject(j);
        String date = obj.getString("date");
        //todo достать нужные поля
    }
}
```

Comment: String date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(new Date());///получаем тякущую дату
                int pars=Integer.parseInt(date1);//преобразуем в инт
                int mount=pars-1;/// -1
                Log.d("myLog","real date==="+mount);///получаем тякущий месяц

                  JSONArray productObj2 = products.getJSONArray(mount);///получаем массив за месяц

Comment: как теперь по date выбрать Sunrise Dhuhr итд что лучше писать в бд ? или hasmap что бы передать в следующее активити ?

Comment: Если массив `productObj2` содержит данные за месяц, в нем циклом можно получить все данные по каждому дню.

Что хранить в БД, а что записывать в Hashmap - это уже вопрос проектирования.